# C++ Templates not being rebuilt on code changes - VS2015

Tags: c++, templates, visual-studio-2015

In Visual C++ 2015, I have a class that is implemented using templates, and while I do have a .cpp file for the class, most of the implementation is in the .h file. In tracking down a bug, I was adding print statements in the template, and I noticed everything that is dependent upon the template code is being rebuilt when it gets changed, but the new code changes in the template are not being reflected.

So, I experimented, and actually introduced a syntax error in the template, and rebuilt. The change in dependency was detected, and everything rebuilt with no error!

When I do a full solution rebuild, the code change gets detected, but not incrementally. Is there something I can do to force rebuild of the template code?

Answer (score 0):

If you turn off pre-compiled headers for the .cpp file associated with the header file containing the template code, the changes get detected and rebuilt.

Do this by right-clicking the .cpp file, "Properties"->"C/C++"->"Precompiled Header" and select "Not using Precompiled Headers". You may need to do a rebuild to clear the existing .pch.